# Scan router connect self assigned ip address(169.254.164.XX) in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, ip-address, lan

I'm working on sample project router connected devices and camera IP address.

I tried these 2 sample projects: [LAN-Scan](https://github.com/mongizaidi/LAN-Scan), [MMlanScan](https://github.com/mavris/MMLanScan).

This sample project showing only IP assigned devices and camera IP address using subnet mask concept. I want to show self-assigned IP address (169.254.164.XX) and DHCP server assigned IP address from router.

Comment: what hinders you?... what have you tried so far?

Comment: my router IP address is 192.168.0.4. Sample project list the router connected devices and camera IP (192.168.0.207,192.168.3.226) shown but self-assigned IP (169.254.164.XX) is missing.

Comment: how did you setup your routing for ip traffic from 192.168.0.0/24 to reach 169.254.0.0/16, and for the answers to return?

Comment: camera set to default IP it automatically change into 169.254.164.XX. In windows using vivotek installation wizard software shown 169.254.164.XX and all other devices IP.

Comment: that does not conclude a routing between 192.168.0.0/24 and 169.254.0.0/16 ... can you ping any host in 169.254.0.0/16 from a host in 192.168.0.0/16?

Comment: i m ping 169.254.164.0 to 169.254.164.254 but all not ping.

Comment: so, you want to establish network communication with an unreachable host, that you have no route for ... if you have a windoes software that can actually find that host, i can probably tell you how it does that: it temporarily changes your NIC configuration to APIPA/ZeroConf, does its thing, and then restores the old config ... i'm not familiar with ios, but i'm pretty sure you will need root access to do something like that ...

Comment: Is possible to get all IP address from my router?
Example : my device IP is 192.168.0.147, subnet mask is 255.255.252.0 and router IP is 192.168.0.4. I want to get all IP address based on subnet mask as well as get self -assigned ip address (169.254.xxx.xxx) from router.

Comment: i think you need to read up on how IP works, especially routing... your router does not know those things ... IF your router is also your DHCP then it knows the DHCP lease table, but getting that from the router is a non-standard task ...but your router does not know about any self assigned addresses, and it will usually not provide routing for them out of the box